# Echoing a message when grep has no result

Tags: quickfix, grep

Is there a way echoing a message if grep has no result and `getqflist()` is empty?

I've tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
au QuickFixCmdPost grep call g:GrepPostActions() 

function! g:GrepPostActions()
  let qflist = getqflist()
  if len(qflist) > 0
    "Move window to the very bottom
    wincmd J
  else 
    "??? QuickFixCmdPost doesn't fire on empty qflist ???
     echo 'No match found in '.getcwd() 
  endif
endfunction
```

Comment: As the help text says "...after a quickfix command is run, before jumping to the first location", it would be valid to not fire the event, if there is no location to jump to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I came up with this solution:

```
function! EchoResultMsg()
  let qflist = getqflist()
  if len(qflist) > 0
    echo 'grep: '.len(qflist).' matches found.'
  else
    echo 'grep: No match found in '.getcwd() 
  endif
endfunction

command! -nargs=+ -complete=file Grep grep <f-args> | cwindow | call EchoResultMsg()
```

The newly defined `:Grep` command calls `cwindow` and `EchoResultMsg` after `grep`. The `cwindow` command doesn't open the quickfix window, if there is no resulted match, but `EchoResultMsg` can check the length of `qflist`.

This is the simplified part of the code. The whole plugin can be found here: https://github.com/mattia72/vim-ripgrep